# Getting joint angles for passive urdf model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm a bit confused about how to get joint states.

I'm trying to set up an inverted pendulum on a two-wheeled cart.
I've successfully attached differential drive, and also control of the revolute joint for the pendulum rod.

But, now I want  to remove any actuators and simply access the state of the passive model.  E.g., I want to view the angle of the rod as it collapses under gravity from vertical to about horizontal.

Do I nevertheless need a joint_state_controller, or even position controllers?  I'm simulating in gazebo, of course.

The joint_states I see published are empty.


`--- 

header:  

seq: 105994 

stamp:  

secs: 2120 

nsecs: 302000000 

frame_id: '' 

name: [] 

position: [] 

velocity: [] 

effort: [] 

---`

Here are links to the relevant files as they stand now...

URDF: http://pastebin.com/MTkTgZmH

YAML:  http://pastebin.com/eD0jK7AZ

Launch: [http://pastebin.com/Zwrrb](http://pastebin.com/ZwrrbGtT)

[image: Screenshot in Gazebo]

My setup...
ROS Indigo, Gazebo 2.2.6.
Linux Mint 17.3 (Rosa) 64-bit.
(3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

I'd love to get angular position and velocity for the three joints (turret_to_rod, motor_to_wheelleft, motor_to_wheellright).

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13844/getting-joint-angles-for-passive-urdf-model/) by [klaatu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2641/klaatu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can add a plugin in your robot description file:

```
<!--Publish joint state from Gazebo-->
        <plugin name="joint_state_publisher" filename="libgazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher.so">
            <robotNamespace>your_robot_name</robotNamespace>
            <jointName>
                turret_to_rod, motor_to_wheelleft, motor_to_wheellright
            </jointName>
            <updateRate>100</updateRate>
            <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        </plugin>
```

---

Originally posted by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) with karma: 284 on 2016-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [klaatu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2641/klaatu/) on 2016-07-06**:
OK, thanks, that worked after I removed controller references in my my launch file. (Actually I now recall I had tried that before, but was disappointed to find no velocity data -- nor effort data.)

`name: ['turret_to_rod', 'motor_to_wheelleft', 'motor_to_wheelright']

position: [-1.6200029645491254, 0.9563870177604148, 0.9066213357244619]

velocity: []

effort: []`


I guess velocity and effort are not implemented?

**Comment by [yossi.ovcharik](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4417/yossi.ovcharik/) on 2018-01-13**:
Still no implementation in Kinetic on 16.04 or am I doing something wrong?