# How to model underactuated joint to extract the angle for controll?

Tags: ros2, rviz, urdf, robot-state-publisher, joint-state-publisher

Assume if I have a pendulum on a robot cart or a trailer on a robot. These are system which passivly follow the robot. If you want to control them how do you access the angle? I have investigated this and there are many deadlinks but I want the simpliest method of having an underactuated link such as the pendulum and trailer work in gazebo and then extract the their angle. My robot is a diff drive robot. I have the system working in Gazebo but the passive joint does not show in Rviz.

I have attempted this:
From this question [How to visualise under-actuated joints in rviz?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/27810/getting-joint-angles-for-passive-urdf-model) i attempted to add the joint_state_publisher plugin however when I call ros2 topic echo /joint_states i get nothing. Previously I just called the joint state publisher from my launch file.

I have attempted this from this question [How to visualise under-actuated joints in rviz?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/98061/how-to-visualise-under-actuated-joints-in-rviz) however adding the transmission elements did not work even when adding the gazebo controller.

I have these ideas.

1. Write a gazebo model plugin that specifically work for my case. This seemed to be a bit much work.
2. [Make the passive joint](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/34077/how-to-make-a-joint-rotate-a-specified-angle) a one dof robot arm with very low PID gains and hope it works or make the one DOF robot work but based on the diff robot state generate trajectories that would make it look like it was simulated.

I hope someone can point me to the correct direction.

Comment: I made it work using a one DOF robot as the underactuated joint. However I would like comments/ideas for future references. I feel the correct approach should be to make the plugins.